# What to change, so that the multiple inserts are done at once and quicker

Tags: php, mysqli

The problem is that I want to make one query to insert all the content of the cart at one time to the database table `ordersdetail` to improve the speed.

In my code below the inserts are now in a for loop using prepared statements. The script below is working, but an insert takes place now at every iteration.

I thought it could be quicker if I put the whole cart in an array, but I got stuck. I can not fix the problem. Any help is appreciated.

**THE SCRIPT**

```
include_once '../../includes/db_connect.php'; 

class Item{
    var $productid;
    var $productnaam;
    var $productomschrijving;
    var $productprijs_excl;
    var $productprijs_incl;
    var $product_btw_tarief;
    var $quantity;
    var $lesuren;
}

session_start();

$order_id = $_SESSION["order_id"];
$klantid = $_SESSION["klantid"];

$insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO ordersdetail (order_id, productid, productnaam, productomschrijving, productprijs_incl, product_btw_tarief, aantal, subtotaalexcl, subtotaal, klantid, lesuren) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
$insert_stmt->bind_param('iissddiddid', $order_id, $productid, $productnaam, $productomschrijving, $productprijs_incl, $product_btw_tarief, $aantal, $subtotaalexcl, $subtotaal, $klantid, $lesuren);                   

$cart = $_SESSION ['cart'];

    for($i = 0; $i < count($cart); $i++){

        $productid = $cart[$i]->productid;
        $productnaam = $cart[$i]->productnaam;
        $productomschrijving = $cart[$i]->productomschrijving;
        $productprijs_incl = $cart[$i]->productprijs_incl;
        $product_btw_tarief = $cart[$i]->product_btw_tarief;
        $subtotaalexcl = $cart[$i]->productprijs_excl * $cart[$i]->quantity;
        $subtotaal = $cart[$i]->productprijs_incl * $cart[$i]->quantity;
        $aantal = $cart[$i]->quantity;
        $lesuren = $cart [$i]->lesuren * $cart[$i]->quantity;

        $insert_stmt->execute();
    }// End for loop
 $insert_stmt->close();
```

**EDITS**

```
$cart = unserialize (serialize ($_SESSION ['cart']));
```

is edited in:

```
$cart = $_SESSION ['cart'];
```

@Nick. The bindstatement is moved outside the loop right after the prepare statement.

Comment: You can move the `bind_param` outside the loop (immediately after the prepare statement).

Comment: Why are you doing `$cart = unserialize (serialize ($_SESSION ['cart']));` instead of just `$cart = $_SESSION ['cart'];`?

Comment: @Nick. bind_param outside the loop right after prepare statement won't work. The parameters are in the loop!

Comment: you only need to use `bind_param` once, then just reassign the variables for each pass through the loop. See the example [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php)

Comment: @Nick. Thanks for your reply. I edit my code conform your advise and it works allso. Is binding the parameters outside the loop, in this case before the loop right after the prepare statement, making the inserts quicker? Isn'it better to execute them in ones? If yes, how do I do that?

Answer (score -1):

After a quick check and it seems that it's not so easy to get the prepared statement escaped query so an alternative is to escape the data without the prepared statement, here is a quick implementation :

```
$order_id = $_SESSION["order_id"];
$klantid = $_SESSION["klantid"];


$cart = unserialize (serialize ($_SESSION ['cart']));
$insert_values = '';
for($i = 0; $i < count($cart); $i++){

    $productid = $cart[$i]->productid;
    $productnaam = $cart[$i]->productnaam;
    $productomschrijving = $cart[$i]->productomschrijving;
    $productprijs_incl = $cart[$i]->productprijs_incl;
    $product_btw_tarief = $cart[$i]->product_btw_tarief;
    $subtotaalexcl = $cart[$i]->productprijs_excl * $cart[$i]->quantity;
    $subtotaal = $cart[$i]->productprijs_incl * $cart[$i]->quantity;
    $aantal = $cart[$i]->quantity;
    $lesuren = $cart [$i]->lesuren * $cart[$i]->quantity;

    //You can escape them during assigning, I did it here to easily see the data types
    //i
    $order_id = (int)$order_id;
    //i
    $productid = (int)$productid;
    //s
    $productnaam = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $productnaam);
    //s
    $productomschrijving = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $productomschrijving);
    //d
    $productprijs_incl = (double) $productprijs_incl;
    //d
    $product_btw_tarief = (double) $product_btw_tarief;
    //i
    $aantal = (int)$aantal;
    //d
    $subtotaalexcl = (double)$subtotaalexcl;
    //d
    $subtotaal = (double)$subtotaal;
    //i
    $klantid = (int) $klantid;
    //d
    $lesuren = (double) $lesuren;

    $insert_values .= "($order_id, $productid, $productnaam, $productomschrijving, $productprijs_incl, $product_btw_tarief, $aantal, $subtotaalexcl, $subtotaal, $klantid, $lesuren),";

}// End for loop

//trim trailing ,
rtrim($insert_values, ",");

$sql = "INSERT INTO ordersdetail (order_id, productid, productnaam, productomschrijving, productprijs_incl, product_btw_tarief, aantal, subtotaalexcl, subtotaal, klantid, lesuren) VALUES " . $insert_values;

$mysqli->query($sql);
```

**Warning** You should add more validations regarding the data you want to insert

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. Thanks for your answer. I prefer to use prepared statements.